# Iterator assignment in a condition - vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, iterator

I have a wrapper for `std::vector` and I've implemented function that replaces a section within a vector with another vector. **I've tried to put the assignment of an iterator directly in the `if` condition and got unexpected results**.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and with `FAIL` defined I get **Debug Assertion Failed! - vector iterators incompatible**. Is it possible that the condition is being evaluated from right to left? I can't get over it.

This is a (poorly implemented) code that reproduces my problem - meant to replace 3rd and 4th elements of `vec` with 1st and 2nd elements of `vec_second`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using std::cout;

//#define FAIL

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<int> vec_second = {6, 7};

    auto it = vec.begin() + 2;

#ifndef FAIL
    it = vec.erase(it, it + vec_second.size());

    if(it == vec.end())
#else
    if((it = vec.erase(it, it + vec_second.size())) == vec.end())
#endif
        vec.reserve(vec.size() + vec_second.size());

    vec.insert(it, vec_second.begin(), vec_second.end());

    for(auto const& x : vec)
        cout << x << " ";
}
```

But runs fine on [Coliru's GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d51a099483c4fa97).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if((it = vec.erase(it, it + vec_second.size())) == vec.end())
```

Since there is no sequence point between them, a compiler is free to call `erase` and `end` in either order.  If `end` gets called first, that iterator is immediately invalidated by `erase`, leading to undefined behavior.

Your `#ifndef FAIL` code is the safe way to do this.